# SetIcon gives symbol error in Java when I want to set icon of label

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, icons

I am trying to Add an Image into jFrame with a label.

I saw on multiple website you should import javax.swing.ImageIcon, create a ImageIcon object and set the icon of the label as the object.

When I set my label I get the following Error:
cannot find symbol symbol: method seticon(Imagelcon) location: variable IbiPic of type Label (Alt-Enter shows hints)

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class HomePage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public HomePage() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")             
    
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        ImageIcon imageAd = new ImageIcon("VWad.jpeg");
        lblPic.setIcon(imageAd);
```

Thank you!

Tried to lblPic.setIcon(ImageAd), result: error

Comment: `setIcon` is a method in [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html), not in [`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Label.html).

Comment: BTW be aware that Java is case sensitive: `setIcon` is not the same as `SetIcon` or `seticon` (both being used in this this question, including in the error message - Now we do not know if you also reported the correct type `Label` or was it `JLabel`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `JLabel` and call `setIcon` to add the `ImageIcon`.

Here's a working example:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MyApp extends JFrame {

    private MyApp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyApp app = new MyApp();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```